# "How can I detect the press of the home key and recently open key in a React Native application and respond to those events?

Tags: react-native

"How can I detect the press of the home key and recently open key in a React Native application and respond to those events?

Could you provide a detailed explanation on how to detect the press of the home key and recently open key in a React Native application and perform a specific action in response to these events? Are there any specific APIs or libraries available in React Native that can be used for this purpose?"

Comment: Question is not clear, can you share more details? In android pressing on `Home` key would send the app to background and in iOS there is nothing as such called Home key!